# How to mention another user on Confluence through the REST API?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to insert a mention in a confluence page through the REST API.

I tried placing the [~xxxx] in the middle of the content but it doesn't seem to work. When I open the page I see [~xxxx] instead of a link to the mentioned user.

I placed that string in the body>storage>value

I have tried also with `<ri:user ri:userkey="xxuserkeyxxx"/>` but, in this case, I do not see anything on the page.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Found the reason why wasn't working, it needs to be:

```
<ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="xxuserkeyxxx"/></ac:link>
```

I was missing the ac:link tag. After adding it, works fine. I wasn't able to find it on the official doc: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a link with the content being the user's user key

```
<ac:link><ri:user ri:userkey="f081435773s808c3014357744847024c" /></ac:link>
```

If you ever need to figure out the correct syntax for storage format:

1. edit a page and, in this case, @mention someone
2. go to the "..." menu and **View Storage Format** to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

ri:userkey is deprecated. Instead use account-id.

```
<ac:link><ri:user ri:account-id=<accountId> /></ac:link>
```